# mongoose production schema doesnt match development schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have very strange problem! I tried reaching out to different people from the community but no one yet knows the answer!

Here is the problem:
I have a NodeJS server connected to MongoDb Atlas via mongoose. My connection is like this:

```
mongoose.set("debug", true);

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

where the MONGO_URI looks like this:
`mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxx@cluster0.ang6l.mongodb.net/xx`

And here is my user model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add a name"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please add an email"],
      unique: true,
    },
.
.
.
pictures: {
      type: [String],
      default: [],
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["client", "employee", "admin", "organization"],
      default: "client",
    },
.
.
.
},
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

As you see it has different fields where pictures is an array of strings.
Every time I want to update profile I use this controller:

```
const updateMyProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // userModel.schema.add({ pictures: [String] });
    // require("mongoose")
    //   .model("User")
    //   .schema.add({ pictures: [String] });

    console.log("userModel.schema.indexes()", userModel.schema.obj);

    const userObj = await userModel.findById(req.user.id);

    console.log("userObj", userObj);
    console.log("userObj.pictures", userObj.pictures);

    console.log("userObj.pictures?.length > 0", userObj.pictures?.length > 0);
    // console.log(
    //   "req.body.picture !== userObj.pictures[0]",
    //   req.body.picture !== userObj.pictures[0]
    // );

    if (
      req.body.picture &&
      userObj.pictures?.length > 0 &&
      req.body.picture !== userObj.pictures[0]
    ) {
      // push new picture to pictures array
      userObj.pictures.unshift(req.body.picture);
      console.log("req.body.picture", req.body.picture);
      console.log("profile", userObj.pictures);
    } else if (req.body.picture && userObj.pictures.length === 0) {
      console.log("before add", [req.body.picture]);
      userObj.pictures = [req.body.picture];
    }
    if (req.body.first_name || req.body.last_name) {
      userObj.name = req.body.first_name + " " + req.body.last_name;
    }
    await userObj.save();
    console.log("----saved userObj", userObj);
    console.log("----saved userObj.pictures:", userObj.pictures);

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("profile updating error", error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});
```

And it works charmingly on the localhost in dev env. But the problem is when I try it on my server in production mode. And here how it goes wrong:
on my controller I get following error on the line where I check `userObj.pictures?.length > 0`

```
profile updating error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at /root/xxx/server/controllers/userController.js:182:53
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

And where I check the schema of user model here: `console.log("userModel.schema.indexes()", userModel.schema.obj);`

the result doesn't have "pictures" in it:

```
userModel.schema.indexes() {
    name: { 
        type: [Function: String], required: [ true, 'Please add a name' ] 
    },
    email: {
        type: [Function: String],
        required: [ true, 'Please add an email' ],
        unique: true
    },
    role: {
        type: [Function: String],
        enum: [ 'client', 'employee', 'admin', 'organization' ],
        default: 'client'
    },
}
```

however when I run the same code on local I see "pictures" in the result. I know I can bypass this by using strict mode but I'm not a fan of using that! I have also tried adding the filed to schema but that didn't work!

```
    userModel.schema.add({ pictures: [String] });
    require("mongoose")
      .model("User")
      .schema.add({ pictures: [String] });
```

any idea whats going on here?

**update:
here is an updated console log:
[image]

Comment: what does the console.log(userObj) returns?

Comment: It returns an object which has the pictures in it.

Comment: a new console log screenshot was added.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked me to clarify the strict mode so I decided to post it as an optional solution (which I'm not in favor of):

```
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.user.id,
        {
          $addToSet: { pictures: req.body.picture },
        },
        {
          strict: false,
        }
      );
```

I can update the user's pictures array both on the local and server using the method above. But I believe not being able to get the same result both on the server and local using the regular method is a bug!